# get attributes of an appended element by jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I want to get id of an appended element by jquery, but i cant, this is my code:
append elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#addSlide").click(function(){
 var slideId="slide"+n;
 var  nslide="<td><img class='projImgs'id='"+slideId+"'onclick='openCustomRoxy()' src='' style='width:75px;height:55px'/> <input id='sldAddr' name='"+slideId+"'   type='hidden' value='' /> </td>";
 $("#slideTr").append(nslide);  
});
```

and The code that get atrribute 'id' :

```
$(".projImgs").click(function(){
var id= $(this).attr('id');
console.log(id);
var source= "http://localhost/exx/admin/fileman/index.html?integration=custom&type=files&img="+id;
console.log(source);
$("#frame").attr('src',source);
});
```

Comment: Use `$("#slideTr").on('click', '.projImgs', function(){`

Answer (score 2):

delegate it with `on` for dynamically added element to its closest parent which I assume is `$("#slideTr")`

```
 $("#slideTr").on("click",".projImgs",function(){
     var id= $(this).attr('id');
         ....
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Event delegation` for added dymanically DOMs . Use immediate parent selector for traverse easily and quickly. If you didn't know the immedaite parent using `$(document)` instead

```
$('#slideTr').on('click', '.projImgs', function(){
     // your code
});
```